# Angular 4 *ngFor performance

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a large dataset I'm iterating over using `*ngFor`, the performance isn't good.

I did some reasearch and found out that it is kind of a known issue due to data binding.

I don't need data bindings in my case because the dataset is static.

Is there a way to "turn off" data binding ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do that is to create a specific component with your ngFor in it.

Then use the change detection strategy OnPush on it [(here)](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy). With this strategy, your component evaluates changes and rerender DOM only if at least one Input is changed.
If you use no input there will be only the initial rendering.

if my response is unclear, can you add a data example to your answer so I cant try to recreate a stackblitz.

Comment: I created a specific component, but I don't see how to pass the data from the parent to it without using Input. Note that the performance is even worse in this case

Comment: if the dataset is static why do you need to pass it with an Input? Cant you just fetch it from a service? And I'm wondering how the performance can be worse, have you add the OnPush detection strategy to your component?

Comment: It is used also in the parent Component, so I want to pass it to the child to save a HTTP call. yes the OnPush detection strategy was added

Comment: could you add the templates and classes of you parent component and child component ?

Answer (score 0):

> large dataset

Depending on "large" it might be a rendering issue
Try virtualizing it https://github.com/kamilkp/ng2-vs-for
And don't show too many elements at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use data binding, then there's no data binding.

If you want to improve the loop performance, you can use a custom trackBy function

```
*ngFor="let x of y; trackBy: tbfn"
tbfn(index, item) { return item.id; }
```

You can also select a subset of you data with

```
get myResults() { return this.myRes.slice(this.page, this.offset); }
```

Comment: Yes I don't need data binding at all, I just need to iterate over the set to display it. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: See the second part of the answer